# pass string with numbers to mysql where in

Tags: php, mysql

I have group of id' s from my query, and i use implode function  or this code to pass it to model, where i wanna use where in clause.

```
$idKurseva = '';
        foreach( $idKursa as $value ) { $idKurseva .= $value['KursID'].','; }

        $idKurseva = rtrim($idKurseva, ",");
        $kkk = $this->statistika_model->soldProductsPrice($autoriIDString);
```

This is my model and function in codeIgniter framework

```
 public function soldProductsPrice($idkurseva)
    {
            $this->db->select('sum(ProductsPrice) * 20/100 AS Zarada, count(IdProduct) AS brojProdaja, IdProduct');
            $this->db->where_in('IdProduct', $idkurseva);
            $this->db->group_by('IdProduct');             


             $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix(TBL_ORDERS_PRODUCTS))->result();
             return   $this->db->last_query();
    }
```

I get query with this structure.

```
SELECT sum(ProductsPrice) * 20/100 AS Zarada, count(IdProduct) AS brojProdaja, `IdProduct` FROM (`cms_cart_orders_products`) WHERE `IdProduct` IN ('10,13') GROUP BY `IdProduct`
```

I think problem is in this

```
IN ('10,13')
```

is it possible to pass something like this

```
IN (10,13)
```

I get empty results

Comment: Use `$idKurseva=array();` and fill it as an array,dont concatenate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    foreach( $idKursa as $value ) { $idKurseva .= $value['KursID'].','; }

    $idKurseva = rtrim($idKurseva, ",");
```

Use implode:

```
$idKurseva = implode(',', $idKursa);
```

But like Mihai said before, pass array to method: where_in